# Sub-collection Firestore get document id when cloud function triggers

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How one can have the document id of a document on the top of hierarchy?

```
export const notifications = functions.firestore
    .document('caseStatus/{case}/0/{milestones}').onUpdate((change)  => {
```

I created a trigger for a sub-collection wild a wildcard "milestones", the document id at that level can be retrieved easily from "change" value.

What I need id the document id of "case", is that possible with cloud functions? Can the function listen for updates on two collection levels?

One solution would be to change the id format of each document and carry that info towards lower levels

Ex:

number £ email £ document specific value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single function cannot listen to two different nested collections at the same time.  You will need to define one function for each collection.

```
// deal with milestone documents here
functions.firestore.document('caseStatus/{case}/0/{milestones}').onUpdate(...)

// deal with case documents here
functions.firestore.document('caseStatus/{case}').onUpdate(...)
```